# Is there a way to specify the window offset for an app spawned in X?

Tags: linux, bash, window, offset, window-managers

I am writing a bash script that calls some apps that run in their own window. However, they appear at a standard position on the screen. I want to be able to specify the screen co-ordinates where they appear.

Is there a setting that can be passed in command line to make this happen? I am presently using openbox and if this is a window manager feature that openbox cannot provide, could anyone recommend another lightweight window manager (fluxbox?) to which I can specify window offsets?

Is there an X setting that can do this for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many X clients support a [`-geometry` argument](http://www.xfree86.org/current/X.7.html#sect6) (sometimes `--geometry`) which allows you to specify size and/or position of the initial window.

Answer (score 0):

[devilspie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/) could be of help you can specify different window properties on compliant window managers.

Some [examples](http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie#examples) are also available.